# How to express concrete method in abstract class on UML2 Class Diagram?

Tags: uml, abstract-class, class-diagram, concrete-inheritance

Problem mentioned in the underlined sentence in this image:

[image]

I have been asked to add concrete public method in a abstract class in UML2.
I am struggling to find the solution as I didn't find any material related this. I know that abstract class can be defined by italic font. But how does one show a concrete public/abstract method in a(n abstract) class?

Comment: Can't see why that question was closed. Maybe the missing verb in the last sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you follow the same rules as for the class being shown italic: show the abstract operation in italic.

[image]

As you can see the operation named `abstract` is rendered in italics indicating that it has the `isAbstract` property set to `true` while the concrete operation named `concrete` is shown in normal font (so being concrete and having `isAbstract` set to `false`).